# oracle::occi::Date.SetDate() is crashing : (exception) Error=32146 : ORA-32146: Cannot perform operation on a null date

Tags: oracle, date, occi

I having the next simple code that get exception "32146 Cannot perform operation on a null date"

```
oracle::occi::Date dt;
dt.setDate(tt.tm_year, tt.tm_mon, tt.tm_mday, tt.tm_hour, tt.tm_min, tt.tm_sec);
```

The tt.tm_year, tt.tm_mon, tt.tm_mday, tt.tm_hour, tt.tm_min, tt.tm_sec values are:

***tm_year=114, tt.tm_mon=1, tt.tm_mday=4, tt.tm_hour=1, tt.tm_min=2, tt.tm_sec=0***

**WHY** do I get exception?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have not explicitly initialised the `dt` variable so it is using the default class constructor and is `NULL`.

Summarising the [C++ Call Interface Programmer's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference013.htm#LNCPP1009) (with your variables), you need to use the class constructor to initialise it to a non-`NULL` value:

> ```c++
> Environment *env = Environment::createEnvironment(Environment::DEFAULT);
> Date dt(env, tt.tm_year, tt.tm_mon, tt.tm_mday, tt.tm_hour, tt.tm_min, tt.tm_sec);
> ```

Comment: Thanks. Indeed.
Also, not understood why it is crashing. Not using any connectivity to the DB. Only populate the Date object to send it later to the DB as parameter to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Need to init with environment.
However, not clear why it is crashing. Not using any connectivity to the DB. Only populate the Date object to send it later to the DB as parameter to the query